# How to interpret multiple calls of rnorm() function in R?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, sampling

I'm using `rnorm()` to generate data for a trainng set. The target is to generate a matrix X with n rows and p columns to represent n sets of p features, and I did so in two ways:

First,

```
X = matrix(rnorm(n*p), n, p)
```

Second,

```
X = matrix(ncol = p, nrow = n)
for (i in 1:p) {
  X[, i] = rnorm(n)
}
```

I was expecting both outputs to be i.i.d. sample data from a normal distribution with mean=0 and sd=1. But I got confused to see that the model coefficients fitted on these two data sets are very different.

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Did you set the seed prior to generating each matrix? If you generate one then the other (without re-initialising the seed) you will get differe Try `set.seed(1); X = matrix(rnorm(n*p), n, p)` and then run the analysis. Then `set.seed(1); X = matrix(ncol = p, nrow = n)
for (i in 1:p) {
  X[, i] = rnorm(n)
}` and run the analysis again. You should get same results now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is really about R syntax and not about the normal distribution or sampling. So I guess it's
'off topic' here, and may be closed.

I'm not quite sure what your difficulty is.
*If you set the same seed before each program,*
then you should fill an $n\times p$ matrix
by columns with exactly the same normal variates.

```
n=5; p=2
set.seed(713)            # set seed
X = matrix(rnorm(n*p), n, p); X
           [,1]        [,2]
[1,] -1.5925966  0.37590371
[2,] -0.1458793  0.28096447
[3,] -1.0048927 -0.60433386
[4,] -1.5337787 -0.03059243
[5,]  0.3318419  0.46158609
set.seed(713)           # set same seed again
X = matrix(ncol = p, nrow = n)
for (i in 1:p) {
 X[, i] = rnorm(n) }
X
           [,1]        [,2]
[1,] -1.5925966  0.37590371
[2,] -0.1458793  0.28096447
[3,] -1.0048927 -0.60433386
[4,] -1.5337787 -0.03059243
[5,]  0.3318419  0.46158609
```

---

But if I've missed the point and you're asking
something else,
then I suggest you replace randomly generated normal variates by sequences of integers. Then the rules
for filling matrices might be clearer to you:

```
n = 5; p = 2; matrix(1:(n*p),n,p)  # n rows, p col
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10

n = 5; p = 2
X = matrix(ncol = p, nrow = n)
for (i in 1:p) {
 X[, i] = 1:n
}
X
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    3    3
[4,]    4    4
[5,]    5    5
```

When `matrix` turns a vector into a matrix, the
default order is to fill the matrix by columns.
(All vectors, unless *specifically* modified, are considered column vectors, even
if they print out as rows.)

```
y = 1:10;  matrix(y, ncol=2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10

y = 1:10;  matrix(y, ncol=2, byrow=T)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    5    6
[4,]    7    8
[5,]    9   10
```

You *can* make row vectors.

```
w = c(1,2,3,4,3,2)   # 'c' for column vector
X = as.matrix(w)
X
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
[4,]    4
[5,]    3
[6,]    2

t(X)  # transpose is a row vector
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    3    2

t(X) %*% X   # matrix multiplication
     [,1]
[1,]   43
X %*% t(X) 
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    3    2
[2,]    2    4    6    8    6    4
[3,]    3    6    9   12    9    6
[4,]    4    8   12   16   12    8
[5,]    3    6    9   12    9    6
[6,]    2    4    6    8    6    4
X*t(X)
Error in X * t(X) : non-conformable arrays
t(w)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    3    2
t(w)%*%w
     [,1]
[1,]   43
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is about R syntax, as BruceET says, but I think that data simulation is an important topic, and that you could (should?) generate your data in another way. You can use the `mvtnorm` package to generate random multivariate matrices and the `scale()` function to ensure that each column has mean=0 and variance=1:

```
> library(mvtnorm)
> n <- 6
> p <- 3
> mean <- rep(0, p)
> sigma <- diag(p)              # identity matrix
> X <- rmvnorm(n, mean=mean, sigma=sigma)
> X
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.4557803 -1.6174866 0.34224496
[2,]  0.7982673 -0.1214584 3.05775038
[3,] -0.2175150  1.1449116 0.07709425
[4,]  0.9070137  0.4484822 1.49516553
[5,] -1.8435512 -2.4068282 1.23142658
[6,] -0.5840670 -1.3760948 0.37929271
> apply(X, MARGIN=2, FUN=mean)
[1] -0.2326054 -0.6547457  1.0971624
> apply(X, MARGIN=2, FUN=sd)
[1] 1.012930 1.360682 1.108703
> X <- scale(X)
> apply(X, MARGIN=2, FUN=mean)
[1]  1.127570e-17 -3.699840e-17  9.483155e-17
> apply(X, MARGIN=2, FUN=sd)
[1] 1 1 1
```

The columns are correlated when $n$ is small, but the correlation decreases (as expected, because `sigma` is an identity matrix) as $n$ grows:

```
> X <- scale(rmvnorm(1000, mean=mean, sigma=sigma))
> cor(X)
            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
[1,]  1.00000000 -0.05327000 -0.01848098
[2,] -0.05327000  1.00000000 -0.01011558
[3,] -0.01848098 -0.01011558  1.00000000
> X <- scale(rmvnorm(10000, mean=mean, sigma=sigma))
> cor(X)
            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
[1,] 1.000000000 0.005957725 0.002865598
[2,] 0.005957725 1.000000000 0.008932789
[3,] 0.002865598 0.008932789 1.000000000
```

You can generate heteroscedastic and corrrelated data by changing `sigma`.